# Need better regex to test for "a" but not "ax"

Tags: regex, reporting-services, vbscript

I use the following regex in SSRS to test for a particular column name in a parameter:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!ColumnNames.Value, ","), "x"), False, True)
```

This will hide a column on a report if it is not one of the chosen columns. This works just fine if there is not another column called "xy".  The string being tested may be "z,x,w", in which case the test works fine; but it may also be "z,xy,w", in which case it will find "x" and display both "x" and "xy".

I tried checking for "x," which only works if "x" is not the last character of the string.  I need to know the syntax to check for both "x," OR "x as the last piece of the string".  Unfortunately *"x"* can have any length.  The basic problem is I do not know how to use an OR in the IIF statement.

I tried the most obvious ways and kept getting errors.  Using "\b" also does not work because there are no spaces in the string (so word boundaries are not applicable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add the delimiter to your check, so that way you're checking the exact string only and not any that just include it:

```
=IIf
  (InStr("," & Join(Parameters!ColumnNames.Value, ",") & ",", ",x,") > 0
  , False
  , True)
```

So this will catch `x` but not `xy`.

One thing to note:

I have added a check to see of `InStr > 0`, as this returns an integer and not a boolean.

Comment: This answer is perfect and simply adds a little bit to what I already understand.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to match a specific column name in an array of column names but do this on a single line to include in the `IIF` statement.

Based on the last technique suggested in [How can I quickly determine if a string exists within an array?](https://web.archive.org/web/20061017134136/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=93) your code would need to be.

```
=IIf((UBound(Filter(Parameters!ColumnNames.Value, "x", True, compare)) > -1), False, True)
```

It doesn't look like there is an actual Regex anywhere?

Comment: This is an interesting solution - I did not think of looking at the array.  However my understanding of filter is that it finds elements that 'contain' the string so this will still return an array containing 'xy'?  I am very new to VB script so could be totally off the mark.  When I tried running this I got the following error which I do not understand:  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Filter' can be called without a narrowing conversion: